# org.jboss.jandex.UnsupportedVersion when upgrading camel from 2.X to 3.X (and camel jandex in general)

Tags: apache-camel

After upgrading from camel 2.X to 3.X I get the following exceptions in my wildfly server:

```
WFLYSRV0002: Loading failed for the annotation index "Some.ear/APP-INF/lib/camel-core-engine-3.14.7.jar/META-INF/jandex.idx" 
with the following exception: org.jboss.jandex.UnsupportedVersion: Version: 10
```

There is a message for every single camel library.

Is there a camel version without jandex or can it be suppressed/deactivated somehow? If it would work (e.g. for a newer wildfly version) would it interfere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the JBoss WildFly team so they can suppress that message or how they want to deal with that.

It smells like differnet jandex versions not supported by WildFly.